# Custom List in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

How to create Custom  Listfield in blackberry like android.

```
image  some Text1
       some Text2
```

one image and its right side some text and below it also a text.

Comment: This will help you see below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414522/blackberry-listfield-development/7454304#7454304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom ListField row with images and text](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-ListField-row-with-images-and-text/td-p/227993) this clearly says how to do this ...